# dll is missing in Python package

Tags: python, dll, anaconda

I want to install in Windows7 64bits, **Winpython** version a .tar package from Anaconda, Windows Compiled.
Anaconda package is 
https://anaconda.org/ccordoba12/boost

```
1) I copy paste into sites-packages all the python code/folder
2) I put the static C++ library  mylib.lib in Libs
3) I put the dll xxxx into system32  and VOW  folders.
```

I still have "dll xxxx is missing..." when I try the following code in Python:

```
   import packageName
```

Questions:

```
 1) Where should I put the dll ?
 2) IS there any in-compatibility between WinPython and Anaconda Python, Win 64 bits ?
```

thanks

Comment: What is the dll that is missing? There should be some message.

Comment: Try Dependency Walker. http://dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Thanks for this, wil have a look.